# The push.apply method and the this argument

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, push, apply

I've been going through a book and need help in answering a very specific question about push.apply.

```
function SpecialArray(){
    var values = new Array();
    values.push.apply(values, arguments);

    values.toPipedString = function(){
        return this.join("|");
    };

    return values;
}

var colors = new SpecialArray("red","blue","green");
console.log(colors.toPipedString());
```

I understand what this code does but am a little lost on :

```
values.push.apply(values, arguments);
```

From what I understand. This uses the push and apply to add an array from the function arguments into 0 , 1 and 2 of values array. What I don't understand is the this argument.

I understand that changing this value will point this into another Object which is useful for a function. In this case, I tried changing values into something else as I'm only pushing the arguments array into the new Array and don't need to change the this pointer, but I get a blank in the results for anything other than values?

Can someone explain to me why changing the thisArg will yield blank? The values.push should already indicate that I want it specifically in the values array and am only using the apply arrArg to join an array into another similar to the concat method.

Comment: By the time you get to `.apply()`, the `.push` method has lost its relationship to `values`. Remember, `this` is only set when you invoke a function. But you're not invoking `.push()` directly. You're invoking `.apply()`, which invokes `.push()` for you. So you need to tell `.apply()` what the `this` value should be of the method you told it to invoke for you.

Comment: ...the `this` value in the `.apply()` method will be the `.push()` method, which is generic. It has no permanent relationship to `values`.

Answer (score 0):

> The values.push should already indicate that I want it specifically in the values array

Nope.

Writing `values.push(...)` will pass `values` as the `this` argument to `push()`.
That is the only way that `push()` knows what to push into.

If you cal it using `apply()`, you need to explicitly pass `values` as `this`.

To put it differently, there is no difference between the functions `values.push`, `[].push`, and `Array.prototype.push`.